# Как сделать интерактивное меню в console?

Tags: bash, golang

Всем привет, при установке npm пакетов, довольно часто встречаю интерактивное меню (примеры на скринах). И не могу понять как это реализовано? Может кто в курсе, и сможет мне привести пример кода (bash or golang)?

Спасибо

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это делается с помощью использования интерактивных возможностей конкретных эмуляторов терминалов и конкретных ОС. В го есть множество пакетов для использования этих возможностей, например [`github.com/gdamore/tcell`](https://github.com/gdamore/tcell). Там есть ссылки на примеры проектов.

<sub>Моё личное мнение: подобные менюшки — блажь, и их вообще не должно быть при установке пакетов.</sub>

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Немного "покопавшись" нашёл ещё несколько вариантов: https://awesome-go.com/#command-line